# GCC 6.3 warning comparison of constant '0' with Boolean expression is always false

Tags: android, c, kernel, gcc-warning

The warring points to this bit of code

```
#define DO_SAFE(do_work, goto_error)                \
 DO_IF(unlikely((do_work) < 0), goto_error)
```

This is from a header file.  I don't understand what this code is trying to do, or compare. To me is seems like do do_work if false then goto error.  But if that was correct would it be

```
 (do_work != 0)
```

but that is just a guess.

Please tell if more info is need.

### Function giving error in c file

```
for (page_num = 0; page_num < PAGE_MAX_NUM; page_num++) {
    DO_SAFE(touch_i2c_write_byte(client, PAGE_SELECT_REG, page_num), error);

for (u_address = DESCRIPTION_TABLE_START; u_address > 10; u_address -= sizeof(struct function_descriptor)) 
{
DO_SAFE(touch_i2c_read(client, u_address, sizeof(buffer), (unsigned char *)&buffer) < 0, error);
```

Comment: What is the `do_work` argument you are using when you use the macro?  Does it call a function that returns a boolean value?  If so, the result will be 0 or 1, neither of which is less than 0, hence you would get a warning about the condition being always false.  The 'unlikely' is a hint to the compiler that the condition probably won't be true.

Comment: I add more of the code to the question.  Wish I understood C better to trace the Constant valve that's being compared to 0

Comment: You've not shown the declarations for `touch_i2c_read()` or `synaptics_ts_page_data_read()` which are both also used in DO_SAFE macro invocations.  Does the code reproduce the problem on all three functions, or only on one — and if one or two of the three, which ones?  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — it would tell you about this so I shouldn't have to be asking for the necessary information.  I'm not going to be able to help much more — Linux kernel programming for Android is outside my realm of expertise.  I can only apply general principles, not specific experience.

Comment: Maybe error: should return -1, like other functions using Do_Safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see the problem (if I scroll horizontally — the lines are rather long):

```
DO_SAFE(touch_i2c_read(client, u_address, sizeof(buffer), (unsigned char *)&buffer) < 0, error);
```

You're testing a `< 0` condition in the macro invocation, which means you end up with the expansion of `DO_SAFE` doing:

```
if ((touch_i2c_read(…) < 0) < 0)
```

and the result of the inner condition never is less than zero.

Use:

```
DO_SAFE(touch_i2c_read(client, u_address, sizeof(buffer), (unsigned char *)&buffer), error);
```

(That has eliminated the `< 0` in your direct invocation of `DO_SAFE`, leaving the macro to test for `< 0`.)

Comment: Well edit and see if It compiles, I hate when OEMs create bad code.  Thank LG for this issue.

Comment: There are still advantages to limiting line widths — I see 83 characters in my browser, and the key information is just off the screen.  In your more heavily indented code, the key information is even further off to the right.  I usually aim for 80, but often don't fuss up to 100; I seldom leave lines as long as that unbroken, and essentially never leave longer lines unbroken.

Comment: Yes there is a lot I have to learn, Still don't know why I can't get Markdown to work to well for me.  Nothing seems formatted the way I want it to be.

Comment: For placing code into a question, write it in the text box as you want to see it (ignore the preview, and don't try using tabs).  Then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the code.  Check the preview to ensure it is correct.  If you copy/paste code, make sure it is tab free before copying.  Generally, use 4 spaces as an indent level, but any choice 2-8 is OK (and some people have used 1, even), as long as it is consistent.

Comment: That was the issue, too bad it's in the code several times. Look at this 

     DO_SAFE((synaptics_ts_page_data_read(client, ANALOG_PAGE, 0x04, 1, &buf1) < 0), error);

what do I do with the brackets, when I remove < 0?

Comment: It's a problem when the code was written and tested with lax compilation options or older compilers and not checked against more recent compilers and fussy compilation options.  At least you know what to look for (the compiler tells you) and the fix is relatively straight-forward now.

Comment: In the example `DO_SAFE((synaptics_ts_page_data_read(client, ANALOG_PAGE, 0x04, 1, &buf1) < 0), error);`, you need to make sure you keep balanced parentheses.  For maximum cleanliness, use: `DO_SAFE(synaptics_ts_page_data_read(client, ANALOG_PAGE, 0x04, 1, &buf1), error);` — but the compiler won't complain if you use `DO_SAFE((synaptics_ts_page_data_read(client, ANALOG_PAGE, 0x04, 1, &buf1)), error);`, though there might circumstances in which those extra parentheses suppress a warning that would not be suppressed when absent (but, OTOH, I've not come up with a concrete example).